# Oracle high_value statistic

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Consider this kind of table :

```
create table t (
   id number,       -- and many many other columns of course
   record_date date -- the date when the rows is inserted
);
```

In this table, we add 400k rows per hour. And every hour, we launch a query using the last hour of data. A `SQL` like :

```
SELECT 
    ... 
FROM t
INNER JOIN ... -- t is joined with many other tables
INNER JOIN ... 
INNER JOIN ... 
INNER JOIN ... 
WHERE 
   t.record_date >= :my_current_date - 1/24
;
```

The problem we have is that the Plan is often bad is this kind of situation. Here is the reason why :

When `Oracle` computes the statistics of the table, it stores the `max(record_date)` in a statistic called **high_value**. So when the `SQL` is launched, `Oracle` compares the filter `t.record_date >= :my_current_date - 1/24` whiting the high_value of the column `record_date`, and believes that hardly no row will be returned (instead of 400k). Therefore the optimization of the following joins cannot be good ...

What is the best solution in this kind of situation ? I could use a hint for example...

Comment: You may want to use CARDINALITY hint.

Comment: Are the 400K rows added to existing rows, or is it just a new 400K rows every hour (i.e. will the table be at 800K after 2 hours, or will it be truncated and a new 400K added?) Also, is there a way for you to gather stats on the table before the query takes place? Depending on the process in place, you could just use insert a "EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLE');" statement before the query is executed. If that won't work (let's say time is a factor,) you could save the stats from the table when has been populated and use those as a point of reference for the optimizer.

Comment: to answer your questions :

- Cardinality hint does not work here because it kind of replaces the **num_rows** statistics, not the **high_value**. Or maybe it can be used in a way I do not know.

- It is 400k rows per hours, and let's consider we never delete anything. (Actually we delete rows older than 5 years, but the software is not 5 year old yet)

- Recomputing the statistics each times could be the solution but I don't think we can afford it because the database is too busy.

Comment: If the query is always the same/similar, you might want to think about using a SQL Profile with forced matching to get the database to use the best execution plan possible, but that wouldn't be a viable option if the format of the query changes.

Comment: Is `t.record_date` indexed?

Comment: Yes t.record_date is indexed

Comment: @jeleb
You can also try to use OPT_ESTIMATE(TABLE t MIN=400000)
But other than 'it may help' - i can't tell much more. The hint is not documented and online blogs are rarely to be 100% trusted.

Comment: OPT_ESTIMATE seems to be the best solution I have, even if I feeel quite insecure by relying on an undocumented hint. I will give it a try.

Comment: It's only optimization hint - the worse it can do is to make your query run even slower.
Some of the most useful hints, like inline, materialize, cardinality are undocumented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the hint OPT_ESTIMATE(TABLE t MIN=400000) and it works so far. Thanks piezol !